# How To Map IIS7 and HOST file to respond to any subdomain

Tags: iis-7, host

I am working on a website LOCALLY running Win7 and IIS7. I want the website to respond to ANY subdomain request like "***.mysite.com".

How do I configure the IIS bindings and host file to allow for this? I can't seem to locate any good tutorials on this.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can anyone else chime in on this that is familiar with IIS7, host files, and approaching this from the right angle.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't enter host headers and your domain's dns records are set to point all subdomains to the website's IP address, the website will catch all requests.

I am not sure about your local setup, but i am running few websites on IIS7 where all subdomains go to the same site.

Comment: Basic ASP.NET local setup. IIS7 with bindings, host file configuration.

DNS entries aren't going to work LOCALLY as I don't need DNS for hosting on the same machine I am developing on. I am looking for a sample host file configuration using some type of subdomain wildcard setup or some way to configure the bindings within the site's IIS7 setup that would allow for any subdomain "abc.mysite.com" or "def.mysite.com" to all route to one IIS website.

The website would pull the subdomain "abc" and lookup database records relative to that "subsite".